# Как исправить ошибку при копирование файлов

Tags: c#, рекурсия

Метод поиска файлов:

```
 private int GetFilesList(string path, out List<string> fileList)
    {
        int result = 1;
        long oneHundredMeg = 100000000;
        fileList = new List<string>();
        string[] Extensions = { ".txt", ".doc", ".cs", ".ico", ".Dll", ".Html", ".Htm", ".Xml", ".Php", ".png", ".jpg", ".gif" };
        if (DirSize(new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(path), oneHundredMeg) > oneHundredMeg)
        {
            result = 0;
            foreach (string fileName in Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
            {
                string ext = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
                if (Array.IndexOf(Extensions, ext) >= 0)
                {
                    fileList.Add(fileName);
                    try
                    {
                        fileList.Add(fileName); 
                    }
                    catch { }
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Метод проверки размера папки:

```
 public static long DirSize(DirectoryInfo d, long aLimit = 0)
    {
        long Size = 0;
        // Add file sizes.
        FileInfo[] fis = d.GetFiles();
        foreach (FileInfo fi in fis)
        {
            Size += fi.Length;
            if (aLimit > 0 && Size > aLimit)
                return Size;
        }
        // Add subdirectory sizes.
        DirectoryInfo[] dis = d.GetDirectories();
        foreach (DirectoryInfo di in dis)
        {
            Size += DirSize(di, aLimit);
            if (aLimit > 0 && Size > aLimit)
                return Size;
        }
        return (Size);
    }
```

Вызываю таким способом:

```
public static string sd = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory);
public static string TxtPath = @"C:\folder\";

 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> files;
        if (GetFilesList(sd, out files) == 0)
        {
            foreach (string ss in files)
            {
                File.Copy(ss, TxtPath, true);
            }
        }
    }
```

При вызове мне пишет: `Не удалось найти часть пути "C:\folder\"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fileList.Add(fileName);
/// ??? это здесь зачем? уберите:
try
{
  fileList.Add(fileName); 
}
catch { }
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9706cfs5(v=vs.110).aspx

```
File.Copy(ss, Path.Combine(TxtPath, Path.GetFileName(ss)), true);
```

Comment: Проглядел) спс за поправку, всё работает отлично!

Comment: @lgor, А как по окончанию сбора файлов, очистить занимаемую память в `List<string>`  Точнее где просто вызвать метод `fileList.Clear();` ?

Comment: Параметр `out List<string> fileList` передается наружу из метода `GetFilesList`, так что очистить его в `GetFilesList` Вы не можете. Локальная переменная `List<string> files;` в методе `button1_Click` будет очищена сборщиком мусора без Вашего участия.

Comment: ещё 1 проблема у меня постоянно размер папки остаётся `46,1 МБ` , как бы я не ставил размер в `long oneHundredMeg = 10000000;` Как исправить?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уделяйте больше внимания формулировкам: "постоянно размер папки остаётся ..." - размер папки на диске? в коде? значение переменной `oneHundredMeg`?

Comment: на диске :). Окей на будущее буду знать).

Comment: А почему размер папки должен измениться? Вы же из нее файлы копируете, но не удаляете.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49731/discussion-between-artes-and-igor).